# unpack array element inot object as key in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

anyway I can unpack an array into an object that each element of array as the key of object and value is 0? something like

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
//I want to have 
//const obj = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.fromEntries` combined with the array `.map` method:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
//I want to have:
//const obj = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(arr.map(x => [x, 0])))
```

Comment: I am using typescript playground but I got this error `Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.`

Comment: @jacobcan118 You must set the "Target" dropdown in the tsconfig to be `ES2019` or later.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to make your required object.

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const ret = arr.reduce((prev, c) => {
  const p = prev;
  p[c] = 0;
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(ret);
```